# @odata.context missing in the odata output, and unable to get the odata output in excel

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, odata

I am trying to implement a .net core OData interface.

I have implemented two controllers (ODataAsset and ODataAssetCost) in it. I am able to get the data of ODataAssetCost in excel, but unable to get the data of ODataAsset in excel. I am able to get the data for both of them in POstmana nd Chrome.

What I have been able to figure out so far is that the data for ODataAsset is not in the OData format. @odata.contex misses here.(Example Below)

*[
    {
        "name": "ASDFG",
        "enabled": false,
        "type": "ZXCV",
....
....
....
....
     }
]*

Wheeras I get @odata.context in the output for ODataAssetCost, as below:

*{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44308/OData/$metadata#Edm.String",
....
....
....
}*

[**ODataAssetController**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eamod.png)

[**ODataAssetCostController**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5AEI.png)

Comment: Posting images of code is discouraged, can you please post the actual code in the question?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your model in the method that returns an IEdmModel (the one with the builder in it) is not the same as the one as you are using as a return value in the controller. So the result from the db just gets serialized into a normal json object.

EdmModel:

```
   public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new DataConventionModelBuilder(serviceProvider);
        builder.EntitySet<YourModel>("YourModels")
        .EntityType

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        // the type of _db.YourModel is not of type YourModel in the Edm model
        return Ok(_db.YourModel);
    }
```

In my case this resulted from the model being defined in different namespaces with the same name and using one namespace in the edm model and an other one in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add both of your models to your Edm model.

```
    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        odataBuilder.EntitySet<ODataAsset>("ODataAsset");
        odataBuilder.EntitySet<ODataAssetCost>("ODataAssetCost");
        return odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```